# Update individual map in cloud firestore document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

**Final Update**
I changed from using a transaction based on the answer below from andresmijares, to using set().

This now allows me to write the data to the DB.

```
var gradeDocRef = db.collection("students").doc(studentId);
                            console.log(gradeDocRef);

                            var setWithMerge = gradeDocRef.set({
                                "UnitGrades": {
                                            [unitNo]: {
                                                "CG": CG,
                                                "PG": PG, 
                                                "TG": TG
                                                }
                                            }
                                }, { merge: true });
```

---

**Edit**
I altered code for the transaction based on the comment from andresmijares below.

`transaction.set(gradeDocRef, {merge: true}, {`

but then get this error?

*Unknown option 'UnitGrades' passed to function Transaction.set(). Available options: merge, mergeFields*

---

I have a cloud firestore database that contains a collection students.
Each student collections contains a student document with a map and submap like below

```
UnitGrades: 
    {
     IT1:
       {                                  
        CG: "F"
        PG: "F"                                          
        TG: "F"
        id: "IT1"
        name: "Fundamentals of IT"
        type: "Exam"
    }
```

I have 10 units within the map UnitGrades
Each student has the same combination of units

I want to update the map based upon an HTML form in bootstrap (the form is working, plus is quite long so not put it in here)

i.e. change the student grades

I have used the firestore transaction update documentation and adapted slightly to take in data from a form in HTML.

```
let studentId = $(this).attr("data-student-id");
let unitNo = $(this).attr("data-unit");
let CG = $(this).attr("data-CG");
let PG = $(this).attr("data-PG");
let TG = $(this).attr("data-TG");

// Create a reference to the student doc.
var gradeDocRef = db.collection("students").doc(studentId);
console.log(gradeDocRef);
    return db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
// This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
    return transaction.get(gradeDocRef).then(function(gradeDoc) {

   if (!gradeDoc.exists) {
     throw "Document does not exist!";
}

// update the grades using a transaction

   transaction.update(gradeDocRef, {

// in here is my error, I need to be able to select the map
// for the variable for UnitNo only and not wipe the other maps

    "UnitGrades": {

    [unitNo]: {

    "CG": CG,

    "PG": PG, 

    "TG": TG                                                }
});
});

}).then(function() {

console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");

}).catch(function(error) {

console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
console.log(studentId);

});
```

The code I have implemented updates the correct unit map but then wipes the rest of the UnitGrades. What I really want is to update the unit map identified in the variable

`UnitNo` and then leave the rest of the units untouched.

e.g. Currently if I update IT1 this correctly updates the grades within the map but then wipes units IT2, IT3, IT12 etc. from the UnitGrades map. I really want IT2, IT3, IT12 etc. to remain in place untouched and IT1 to be updated with the new values. e.g "F" changes to "P"

Comment: Instead of update, use set and pass { merge: true } as second argument

Comment: @andresmijares I have tried that, edited original question above to show the error I now get?

Comment: it looks you have argument error, let me write an answer for you to check, i meant the second argument after the reference ^^ sorry for this

Answer (score 26, accepted):

change these lines:

```
transaction.update(gradeDocRef, {
    "UnitGrades": {
    [unitNo]: {
       "CG": CG,
       "PG": PG, 
       "TG": TG                                                }
});
```

for this

```
transaction.set(gradeDocRef, {
    `UnitGrades.${unitNo}`: {
       "CG": CG,
       "PG": PG, 
       "TG": TG 
}, { merge: true });
```

**It works like this as far as I know:**

assuming you doc looks like this:

```
 {
   "fantasticsFours": {
     "thing": { ... },
     "susan": { ... },
     "mister": { ... }
   }
 }
```

we need to add `{"humanTorch" :{...}}`

**With set + merge**

```
db.collection('heroes').doc(`xxxXXXxxx`).set({
  "fantasticsFours": {
    "humanTorch":{ ... }
  }
}, {merge:true})
```

will result in this data:

```
 {
   "fantasticsFours": {
     "thing": { ... },
     "susan": { ... },
     "mister": { ... },
     "humanTorch":{ ... }
   }
 }
```

**with Update**

```
db.collection('heroes').doc(`xxxXXXxxx`).update({
  "fantasticsFours": {
    "humanTorch":{ ... }
  }
})
```

will result in this data:

```
 {
   "fantasticsFours": {
     "humanTorch":{ ... }
   }
 }
```

More [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.8.x/DocumentReference#update)

Comment: I now get an error and it seems to update all previously updated grades within the map - firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myctec-cfbs/databases/(default)/documents:commit:1 POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myctec-cfbs/databases/(default)/documents:commit 400

Comment: So It will update all units now that have a grade edited. Rather than just the unitNo being looked at.

Comment: Is it because each time gradeDocRef is being added to rather than starting afresh on each loading of the form? Is there a way to clear this once the document has been updated?

Comment: i just read your code better, why are u using a transaction here? why not just use set directly? take a look at this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions, it doesnt feel like it fit your use case

Comment: I have updated the code to use set directly, but have the same error as I had when using your method for the transaction. I have edited the original post to explain what the issue is now.

Comment: are u checking this part? `UnitGrades.${unitNo}`, the other answer made a better job explaining the case, make sure you notice part i just mentioned

Comment: I have selected this answer as I ended up moving to set merge. However both answers helped me resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for guiding about updating. How to get individual map information?

Answer (score 2):

The following should do the trick:

```
  //....
  return db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
    return transaction
      .get(gradeDocRef)
      .then(function(gradeDoc) {
        if (!gradeDoc.exists) {
          throw 'Document does not exist!';
        }

        // update the grades using a transaction


        transaction.update(
          gradeDocRef,
          'UnitGrades.' + unitNo,
          {
            CG: CG,

            PG: PG,

            TG: TG
          }
          // in here is my error, I need to be able to select the map
          // for the variable for UnitNo only and not wipe the other maps
        );
      })
      .then(function() {
        console.log('Transaction successfully committed!');
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Transaction failed: ', error);
        console.log(studentId);
      });
```

---

By doing

```
transaction.update(gradeDocRef, {
    "UnitGrades": { ... }
});
```

you are replacing the **entire** `UnitGrades` field by a new map, therefore you erase the existing map and submaps values.

What you need to do is to only replace a specific "submap". For that you need to use the [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation), as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction#update) for the `update()` method: "Fields can contain dots to reference nested fields within the document."

Note that there are two different ways to call the `update()` method:

```
update(documentRef: DocumentReference, data: UpdateData): Transaction
```

or

```
update(documentRef: DocumentReference, field: string | FieldPath, value: any, ...moreFieldsAndValues: any[]): Transaction
```

In this case we use the second way and we define the path of the nested "submap" with `'UnitGrades.' + unitNo` (dot notation).

---

**HTML Tester page**

If you want to test the proposed solution, just save locally the following code as an HTML file and open it in a browser after you have a/Adapted the Firebase config and b/ created a Firestore document with id `1` under the `students` collection. Then change the value of `unitNo`, refresh the page in the browser and you will see the updates in the DB.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: 'xxxxxx',
        authDomain: 'xxxxxx',
        databaseURL: 'xxxxxx',
        projectId: 'xxxxxx',
        appId: 'xxxxxx'
      };

      firebase.initializeApp(config);

      var db = firebase.firestore();

      let studentId = '1';
      let unitNo = 'IT1';
      let CG = 'F';
      let PG = 'F';
      let TG = 'F';

      // Create a reference to the student doc.
      var gradeDocRef = db.collection('students').doc(studentId);
      console.log(gradeDocRef);
      db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
        // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
        return transaction
          .get(gradeDocRef)
          .then(function(gradeDoc) {
            if (!gradeDoc.exists) {
              throw 'Document does not exist!';
            }

            transaction.update(
              gradeDocRef,
              'UnitGrades.' + unitNo,
              {
                CG: CG,

                PG: PG,

                TG: TG
              }

            );
          })
          .then(function() {
            console.log('Transaction successfully committed!');
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Transaction failed: ', error);
            console.log(studentId);
          });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be good if you also explained why this works, and why the original code does not.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. It throws out an error in the console - Unexpected token +

Comment: @user1693026 Actually I have thoroughly tested it and it should work normally.

Comment: I have double checked and tested the code to use your answer but even though I now get an update again get the same issue as identified when using the merge. Every time I re-run the code on a new document it updates all the previous updated values. the error coming out is ----> firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myctec-cfbs/databases/(default)/documents:commit:1 POST firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myctec-cfbs/databases/… 400

Comment: @user1693026 I've just added to my answer the code of a web page that you can use to test that the proposed solution actually works.