# how to update a map FIRESTORE value with a key JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

collection name user and a collection name query. 
each user document holds a map name seenQueries with string (queryID) : number.
given a user and a queryID (key) i wish to update its number (the value). the rest of the documents fields should remain untouched.

```
function updateQuerySeen(userID, queryId) {

  var userRef = db.collection("users").doc(userID);
  var queryRef = db.collection("query").doc(queryID);
  const promise1 = userRef.get();
  const promise2 = queryRef.get();
  Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then((values) => {
    doc1 = values[0];
    doc2 = values[1];

    curMsgArrayLen = doc2.data().msgArrayLen;

    // Uupdate seenQueries map key:queryID
    userRef.update({
      seenQueries.queryID: curMsgArrayLen;    // DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK
    }).then(function () {
      //console.log("setDocument);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("UPDATE user's seen query failed ", error);
    });
  });
```

looked at google API, but it doesn't seem to work https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map

saw this answer [Update individual map in cloud firestore document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56506789/update-individual-map-in-cloud-firestore-document) but wasn't sure which one fits my objective, and this one [How to update fields in Firestore map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514496/how-to-update-fields-in-firestore-map)  didn't work

thank you!

Comment: What doesn't work about this code when you run it? So: if you step through it in a debugger, does each variable have the value you'd expect it to have? If so, are there any error messages? If not, what is the result in the database after running this code?

Comment: sorry if that wasn't clear, with a debugger it prints to console exactly what i thought it would, but only prints (console.log) and not returns, not sure why though

Comment: Please update your question to show this in a way that we can see too. We can't see you running it in the debugger, so `console.log` is typically the best way to ensure you and us are looking at the same things.